# Websphere application server LDAP connection pool

Tags: ldap, websphere, connection-pooling, websphere-8

We are using websphere application server 8.5.0.0. we have a requirement where we have to query a LDAP server to get the customer  details. I tried to configure the connection pool as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/config.html).

I passed the below JVM arguments

```
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize=5
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=60000
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug=all
```

Below is a sample code snippet

```
Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
...
...
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "5000");
InitialDirContext c = new InitialDirContext(env);
...
...
c.close();
```

I have two issues here

1. When I am calling the service for the 6th time, I am getting javax.naming.ConnectionException: Timeout exceeded while waiting for a connection: 5000ms. I checked the connection pool debug logs and I noticed the connections are not returning back to the pool immediately despite closing the context safely in a finally block. The connections are released after some time and expired after sometime after the release. There after if I call the service again, it connects to the LDAP server but new connections are being created.
2. I tried to execute the code and I am able to see the connection pool debug logs. But the logs are being logged in System.Err log. Is this an issue? Can I ignore it?

But when I run the code as a standalone application(multithreaded with loop of 50 times), the connections are returned/released immediately.

Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting that the maxsize is 5 and your failures are at 6. Try setting maxsize=125. (I checked what ours was set at). Also, you may want to configure this as IBM recommends. (I found this link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/tuningtheaccesstotheldapserver.html)

Comment: Just to make sure, may you be accessing LDAP over SSL? Second link you've provided tells that only non-SSL plain or no auth connections are pooled by default and you must also specify "-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol=plain ssl" if you're using SSL

Comment: We are not using LDAP over SSL. We use simple authentication. And this is a Dev server. Not sure about the prod LDAP server.